# В чем заключается проблема моментального закрытия exe py файла

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Код

```
from threading import Thread
import win32api
import pymem
import keyboard
from math import atan2, sqrt, pi, asin, isnan
import time
WH, BHOP, N_Flash, Trigger, Aim, Radar = True, True, True, True, True, True
aimlock = True
pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client_panorama.dll").lpBaseOfDll
engine = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "engine.dll").lpBaseOfDll
# offsets
m_vecOrigin = 0x138
m_iHealth = 0x100
m_vecViewOffset = 0x108
dwLocalPlayer = 0xD2FB84
m_bGunGameImmunity = 0x3930
m_vecVelocity = 0x114
dwForceAttack = 0x3175088
m_iCrosshairId = 0xB3D4
m_dwBoneMatrix = 0x26A8
dwClientState_ViewAngles = 0x4D88
m_iShotsFired = 0xA380
dwClientState_GetLocalPlayer = 0x180
m_aimPunchAngle = 0x302C
dwClientState = 0x589DCC
dwRadarBase = 0x5178824
m_flFlashMaxAlpha = 0xA40C
dwGlowObjectManager = 0x528B880
m_iTeamNum = 0xF4
dwEntityList = 0x4D43AB4
m_fFlags = 0x104
m_iGlowIndex = 0xA428
dwForceJump = 0x51ED750
m_bSpottedByMask = 0x980
m_bSpotted = 0x93D
aimfov = 7
aimbone = 8
enginepointer = pm.read_int(engine + dwClientState)


def checkindex():
    localplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
    for y in range(64):
        if pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + y * 0x10):
            entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + y * 0x10)
            if localplayer == entity and y:
                return y


def radar():
    while True:
        if pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer):
            localplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
            localplayer_team = pm.read_int(localplayer + m_iTeamNum)
            for i in range(64):
                if pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10):
                    entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10)
                    entity_team = pm.read_int(entity + m_iTeamNum)
                    if entity_team != localplayer_team:
                        pm.write_int(entity + m_bSpotted, 1)


radar = Thread(target=radar)
radar.start()


def buny():
    while True:
        if BHOP and pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer):
            player = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
            force_jump = client + dwForceJump
            on_ground = pm.read_int(player + m_fFlags)

            if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
                if on_ground == 257:
                    pm.write_int(force_jump, 5)
                    time.sleep(0.17)
                    pm.write_int(force_jump, 4)



t1 = Thread(target=buny)
t1.start()


def no_flash():
    while True:
        if N_Flash and pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer):
            localplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
            try:
                flash_value = localplayer + m_flFlashMaxAlpha
                pm.write_float(flash_value, float(0))
                time.sleep(0.0001)
            except pymem.exception.MemoryReadError:
                pass
            except pymem.exception.MemoryWriteError:
                pass


no_flash = Thread(target=no_flash)
no_flash.start()


def rcs():
    global amount
    oldpunchx = 0.0
    oldpunchy = 0.0
    while True:
        if pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            rcslocalplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
            rcsengine = pm.read_int(engine + dwClientState)
            if pm.read_int(rcslocalplayer + m_iShotsFired) > 2:
                rcs_x = pm.read_float(rcsengine + dwClientState_ViewAngles)
                rcs_y = pm.read_float(rcsengine + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4)
                punchx = pm.read_float(rcslocalplayer + m_aimPunchAngle)
                punchy = pm.read_float(rcslocalplayer + m_aimPunchAngle + 0x4)
                newrcsx = rcs_x - (punchx - oldpunchx) * 2
                newrcsy = rcs_y - (punchy - oldpunchy) * 2
                oldpunchx = punchx
                oldpunchy = punchy
                if nanchecker(newrcsx, newrcsy) and checkangles(newrcsx, newrcsy):
                    pm.write_float(rcsengine + dwClientState_ViewAngles, newrcsx)
                    pm.write_float(rcsengine + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4, newrcsy)
            else:
                oldpunchx = 0.0
                oldpunchy = 0.0


rcs = Thread(target=rcs)
rcs.start()


def wallhack():
    while True:
        if pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer):
            for x in range(64):
                localplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
                localplayer_team = pm.read_int(localplayer + m_iTeamNum)
                if pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + x * 0x10):
                    entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + x * 0x10)
                    spotted = pm.read_int(entity + m_bSpottedByMask)
                    index = checkindex()
                    entity_team = pm.read_int(entity + m_iTeamNum)
                    glow_manager = pm.read_int(client + dwGlowObjectManager)
                    entity_glow = pm.read_int(m_iGlowIndex + entity)
                    if index and entity and entity_team != localplayer_team and spotted == 1 << index:
                        pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x4, float(3))  # R
                        pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x8, float(0))  # G
                        pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0xC, float(2.5))  # B
                        pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x10, float(1))
                        pm.write_int(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x24, 1)
                    elif index and spotted != 1 << index and entity and entity_team != localplayer_team:
                        pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x8, float(1))  # G
                        pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0xC, float(0))  # B
                        pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x10, float(1))
                        pm.write_int(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x24, 1)


wallhack = Thread(target=wallhack)
wallhack.start()


def trigger():
    while True:
        if Trigger and pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer):
            localplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
            localplayer_team = pm.read_int(localplayer + m_iTeamNum)
            entity1 = pm.read_int(localplayer + m_iCrosshairId)
            if entity1 > 0 and entity1 <= 64:
                entity2 = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + (entity1 - 1) * 0x10)
                entity_team = pm.read_int(entity2 + m_iTeamNum)
                if localplayer_team != entity_team and pm.read_int(client + dwForceAttack) != 5:
                    for x in range(10):

                        shooting = True
                        pm.write_int(client + dwForceAttack, 5)
                        if localplayer_team != entity_team and shooting == True:
                            shooting = False
                            pm.write_int(client + dwForceAttack, 4)


t = Thread(target=trigger)
t.start()

bone = 8


def nanchecker(first, second):
    if isnan(first) or isnan(second):
        return False
    else:
        return True


def calc_distance(current_x, current_y, new_x, new_y):
    distancex = new_x - current_x
    if distancex < -89:
        distancex += 360
    elif distancex > 89:
        distancex -= 360
    if distancex < 0.0:
        distancex = -distancex

    distancey = new_y - current_y
    if distancey < -180:
        distancey += 360
    elif distancey > 180:
        distancey -= 360
    if distancey < 0.0:
        distancey = -distancey
    return distancex, distancey


def checkangles(x, y):
    if x > 89:
        return False
    elif x < -89:
        return False
    elif y > 360:
        return False
    elif y < -360:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def normalizeAngles(viewAngleX, viewAngleY):
    if viewAngleX > 89:
        viewAngleX -= 360
    if viewAngleX < -89:
        viewAngleX += 360
    if viewAngleY > 180:
        viewAngleY -= 360
    if viewAngleY < -180:
        viewAngleY += 360
    return viewAngleX, viewAngleY


def Magnitude(vec_x, vec_y, vec_z):
    return sqrt(vec_x * vec_x + vec_y * vec_y + vec_z * vec_z)


def Subtract(src_x, src_y, src_z, dst_x, dst_y, dst_z):
    diff_x = src_x - dst_x
    diff_y = src_y - dst_y
    diff_z = src_z - dst_z
    return (diff_x, diff_y, diff_z)


def Distance(src_x, src_y, src_z, dst_x, dst_y, dst_z):
    diff_x, diff_y, diff_z = Subtract(src_x, src_y, src_z, dst_x, dst_y, dst_z)
    return Magnitude(diff_x, diff_y, diff_z)


def calcangle(src_x, src_y, src_z, dst_x, dst_y, dst_z):
    x = -atan2(dst_x - src_x, dst_y - src_y) / pi * 180.0 + 180.0
    y = asin((dst_z - src_z) / Distance(src_x, src_y, src_z, dst_x, dst_y, dst_z)) * 180.0 / pi
    z = 0.0
    return x, y


def GetBestTarget(local):
    while True:
        olddist = 1.7976931348623157e+308
        newdist = 0
        target = None
        if local:
            localplayer_team = pm.read_int(local + m_iTeamNum)
            for x in range(64):
                if pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + x * 0x10):
                    entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + x * 0x10)
                    spotted = pm.read_int(entity + m_bSpottedByMask)
                    index = checkindex()
                    entity_health = pm.read_int(entity + m_iHealth)
                    gungameimmunity = pm.read_int(entity + m_bGunGameImmunity)
                    entity_team = pm.read_int(entity + m_iTeamNum)
                    if index and localplayer_team != entity_team and entity_health > 0 and gungameimmunity != 1 and spotted == 1 << index:
                        entity_bones = pm.read_int(entity + m_dwBoneMatrix)
                        localpos_x = pm.read_float(local + m_vecOrigin)
                        localpos_y = pm.read_float(local + m_vecOrigin + 4)
                        localpos_z = pm.read_float(local + m_vecOrigin + 8)

                        localpos_x_angles = pm.read_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles)
                        localpos_y_angles = pm.read_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4)
                        localpos_z_angles = pm.read_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x8)

                        entitypos_x = pm.read_float(entity_bones + 0x30 * bone + 0xC)
                        entitypos_y = pm.read_float(entity_bones + 0x30 * bone + 0x1C)
                        entitypos_z = pm.read_float(entity_bones + 0x30 * bone + 0x2C) + 64

                        X, Y = calcangle(entitypos_x, entitypos_y, entitypos_z, localpos_x, localpos_y, localpos_z)
                        newdist = Distance(localpos_x_angles, localpos_y_angles, localpos_z_angles, entitypos_x,
                                           entitypos_y, entitypos_z)
                        if newdist < olddist:
                            olddist = newdist
                            target = entity
            if target:
                return target


def aimthread():
    global localpos3
    while True:
        if pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer):
            aimlocalplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
            aimflag = pm.read_int(aimlocalplayer + m_fFlags)
            aimteam = pm.read_int(aimlocalplayer + m_iTeamNum)
            enginepointer = pm.read_int(engine + dwClientState)

            for y in range(32):
                if pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + y * 0x10):

                    aimplayer = GetBestTarget(aimlocalplayer)
                    aimplayerbone = pm.read_int(aimplayer + m_dwBoneMatrix)
                    gungameimmunity = pm.read_int(aimplayer + m_bGunGameImmunity)
                    aimplayerteam = pm.read_int(aimplayer + m_iTeamNum)
                    aimplayerhealth = pm.read_int(aimplayer + m_iHealth)
                    if aimplayerteam != aimteam and aimplayerhealth > 0 and gungameimmunity != 1:
                        localpos1 = pm.read_float(aimlocalplayer + m_vecOrigin)
                        localpos2 = pm.read_float(aimlocalplayer + m_vecOrigin + 4)
                        if aimflag == 263:
                            localpos3 = pm.read_float(aimlocalplayer + m_vecOrigin + 8) + 45
                        elif aimflag == 257:
                            localpos3 = pm.read_float(aimlocalplayer + m_vecOrigin + 8) + 62
                        elif aimflag == 256:
                            localpos3 = pm.read_float(aimlocalplayer + m_vecOrigin + 8) + 64
                        enemypos1 = pm.read_float(aimplayerbone + 0x30 * bone + 0xC)
                        enemypos2 = pm.read_float(aimplayerbone + 0x30 * bone + 0x1C)
                        enemypos3 = pm.read_float(aimplayerbone + 0x30 * bone + 0x2C)

                        targetline1 = enemypos1 - localpos1
                        targetline2 = enemypos2 - localpos2
                        targetline3 = enemypos3 - localpos3

                        viewanglex = pm.read_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles)
                        viewangley = pm.read_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4)

                        if targetline2 == 0 and targetline1 == 0:
                            yaw = 0
                            if targetline3 > 0:
                                pitch = 270
                            else:
                                pitch = 90
                        else:
                            yaw = (atan2(targetline2, targetline1) * 180 / pi)
                            if yaw < 0:
                                yaw += 360
                            hypo = sqrt(
                                (targetline1 * targetline1) + (targetline2 * targetline2) + (targetline3 * targetline3))
                            pitch = (atan2(-targetline3, hypo) * 180 / pi)

                            if pitch < 0:
                                pitch += 360

                        pitch, yaw = normalizeAngles(pitch, yaw)
                        if checkangles(pitch, yaw):

                            distance_x, distance_y = calc_distance(viewanglex, viewangley, pitch, yaw)

                            if distance_x < aimfov and distance_y < aimfov:

                                if nanchecker(pitch, yaw):
                                    pm.write_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles, pitch)
                                    pm.write_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4, yaw)



                            elif distance_x < aimfov and distance_y < aimfov and pm.read_int(aimlocalplayer + m_iShotsFired) >= 1:

                                if nanchecker(pitch, yaw):
                                    pm.write_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles, pitch)

                                    pm.write_float(enginepointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4, yaw)


aimthread()
```

По идеи, так как есть потоковые функции, exe файл не должен моментально закрываться. Превращал в exe с помощью pyinstaller.  pyinstaller -i "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\illegal project\icon.ico" -F multihack.py.Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Запусти с командной строки.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XNI9DjH, тот же самый код.

Comment: Напишите текстом, картинку мылит с телефона

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы еще пишете код, в самом начале пропишите import time. Так вы импортируете модуль time, а в конце напишите sleep(999999)
Таким образом когда вы вашу прогу скомпилите в exe, то она закроется через 999999 секунд

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).